# SVG markers broken in internet explorer?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg

This svg code displays an arrow in firefox and chrome, but is broken in internet explorer 11:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">

    <defs>
      <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="5" markerHeight="6" refx="5" refy="2" orient="auto">
        <path d="M0,0 L0,4 L5,2.5 L5,1.5 L0,0" style="fill:red;" ></path>
      </marker>
    </defs>

    <path d="M0,0 L50,50"
        style="stroke:red; stroke-width: 10px; fill: none;
           marker-end: url(#arrow);"
    ></path>

  </svg>
```

See it yourself at
https://jsfiddle.net/ns3qfau5/6/

Comment: pedantry comment: your marker as quoted has no id, so I'm surprised it works. >.< . . . the jsfiddle does

Comment: Thanks @OwenBeresford - fixed now. I ended up using http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/ btw...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the **stroke: none;** in tour path style. Like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <defs>
        <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="5" markerHeight="6" refx="5" refy="2" orient="auto">
            <path d="M0,0 L0,4 L5,2.5 L5,1.5 L0,0" style="fill:red; stroke: none;" ></path>
        </marker>
    </defs>

    <path  d="M0,0 L50,50"
          style="stroke:red; stroke-width: 10px; fill: none;
                 marker-end: url(#arrow);"
    ></path>
</svg>
```

It's working in IE-11.

Comment: This is the right answer! According to Dev Console, it even works down to ie 9. Thank you Serhij!

Comment: No problem Swiss.

Answer (score 1):

IE has a bug where it doesn't support markers that are defined with `markerUnits="strokeWidth"`. It always has, and it didn't get fixed until Edge.
This is a real pain because "strokeWidth" is the default setting for the `markerUnits` attribute.

In fact IEs support of markers is pretty bad in general. There are other bugs with markers also (eg. see below).

The only workaround is to use `markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` instead.  To convert your particular marker definition to that form, you have to multiply all your marker values by 10, because that is the stroke width your line has.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">

  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="50" markerHeight="60" refx="50" refy="20" orient="auto" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path d="M0,0 L0,40 L50,25 L50,15 L0,0" style="fill:red;" ></path>
    </marker>
  </defs>

  <path  d="M0,0 L50,50"
         style="stroke:red; stroke-width: 10px; fill: none;
                marker-end: url(#arrow);"
  ></path>

</svg>
```

Even converted, the marker still isn't perfect - which is what I meant by other marker bugs in IE. :(

Comment: Thanks Paul! You are right - that sort of solves the issue. However: I am not so picky about the way to implement this arrow: is there a better way than this "marker" feature? I am not an expert in SVG. I just want a straight arrow that I can manipulate easily through javascript. Any suggestion welcome!

Comment: Markers are the obvious way. But you also have the option of just adding the arrow head yourself.

Comment: I am aware this would be a separate question, and I am not sure how to even word it: is it possible to parametrize an SVG arrrow (ie without marker) and then give it two coordinates for start and end?

Comment: Yes, but you would obviously need to use Javascript.  For example, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737478/block-arrow-using-svg).