# Animated growing arrow link

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate

[image: start]

[image: finish]

Hi, I was wondering how one would go about animating an svg arrow like above (on hover).

I have tried playing around with CSS transforms, but they also scale the arrow-head which is no good. I assume the correct way to do this is using SVGs animations, but I don't know where to start.
For example I would the following arrow (line only) to grow and arrow head to move accordingly.

```
<svg width="600px" height="100px">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="0" refY="3" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth">
      <path d="M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z" fill="#f00" />
    </marker>
  </defs>

  <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"     marker-end="url(#arrow)" />
</svg>
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create growing arrow by using "respoinsive" SVG like this.

```css
svg{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transition:width 2s ease;
  overflow: visible;
}
svg:hover{
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <marker id="m" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="8" 
    refX="0" refY="1" viewBox="0 0 1 2">
      <polygon points="0,0 1,1 0,2" fill="black"/>
    </marker>
 </defs>
  <line x1="0" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%" 
  stroke-width="2" marker-end="url(#m)" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

There are some points to implement.

- `svg` has no `viewBox` (so it is "responsive" SVG).
- Line of arrow is defined by relative position of (root) `svg` size.
- Arrow head is defined by `marker` element.
- Growing animation is defined by CSS transition which animate width of `svg`. So, arrow grows with `svg` size.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! Could you give a hint how would one go about making a left facing arrow as well?

Comment: You should create another marker element and set this to `marker-start` property of `line` element.

Comment: you need to add `stroke="none"` in `polygon` otherwise IE will get a black rectangle instead of the triangle. see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42140313/3448527)

Answer (score -1):

In order to animate the individual SVG elements like HTML elements, you'll need to embed the SVG directly into the page like this:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   width="612px" height="502.174px" viewBox="0 65.326 612 502.174" enable-background="new 0 65.326 612 502.174"
   xml:space="preserve" class="logo">

<ellipse class="ground" cx="283.5" cy="487.5" rx="259" ry="80"/>
<path class="kiwi" d="M210.333,65.331C104.367,66.105-12.349,150.637,1.056,276.449c4.303,40.393,18.533,63.704,52.171,79.03
  c36.307,16.544,57.022,54.556,50.406,112.954c-9.935,4.88-17.405,11.031-19.132,20.015c7.531-0.17,14.943-0.312,22.59,4.341
  c20.333,12.375,31.296,27.363,42.979,51.72c1.714,3.572,8.192,2.849,8.312-3.078c0.17-8.467-1.856-17.454-5.226-26.933
  c-2.955-8.313,3.059-7.985,6.917-6.106c6.399,3.115,16.334,9.43,30.39,13.098c5.392,1.407,5.995-3.877,5.224-6.991
  c-1.864-7.522-11.009-10.862-24.519-19.229c-4.82-2.984-0.927-9.736,5.168-8.351l20.234,2.415c3.359,0.763,4.555-6.114,0.882-7.875
  c-14.198-6.804-28.897-10.098-53.864-7.799c-11.617-29.265-29.811-61.617-15.674-81.681c12.639-17.938,31.216-20.74,39.147,43.489
  c-5.002,3.107-11.215,5.031-11.332,13.024c7.201-2.845,11.207-1.399,14.791,0c17.912,6.998,35.462,21.826,52.982,37.309
  c3.739,3.303,8.413-1.718,6.991-6.034c-2.138-6.494-8.053-10.659-14.791-20.016c-3.239-4.495,5.03-7.045,10.886-6.876
  c13.849,0.396,22.886,8.268,35.177,11.218c4.483,1.076,9.741-1.964,6.917-6.917c-3.472-6.085-13.015-9.124-19.18-13.413
  c-4.357-3.029-3.025-7.132,2.697-6.602c3.905,0.361,8.478,2.271,13.908,1.767c9.946-0.925,7.717-7.169-0.883-9.566
  c-19.036-5.304-39.891-6.311-61.665-5.225c-43.837-8.358-31.554-84.887,0-90.363c29.571-5.132,62.966-13.339,99.928-32.156
  c32.668-5.429,64.835-12.446,92.939-33.85c48.106-14.469,111.903,16.113,204.241,149.695c3.926,5.681,15.819,9.94,9.524-6.351
  c-15.893-41.125-68.176-93.328-92.13-132.085c-24.581-39.774-14.34-61.243-39.957-91.247
  c-21.326-24.978-47.502-25.803-77.339-17.365c-23.461,6.634-39.234-7.117-52.98-31.273C318.42,87.525,265.838,64.927,210.333,65.331
  z M445.731,203.01c6.12,0,11.112,4.919,11.112,11.038c0,6.119-4.994,11.111-11.112,11.111s-11.038-4.994-11.038-11.111
  C434.693,207.929,439.613,203.01,445.731,203.01z"/>
<filter id="pictureFilter" >
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="15" />
</filter>
</svg>
```

After doing this, you can use CSS animations on any of the individual SVG elements, just like HTML elements. For example, you could do the following:

```
svg ellipse { animate: grow 3s infinite; }
```

Without having the exact SVG code for your arrow, I can't give you more specific direction than that, but can point you in the direction of this article: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/