# Svg defs encapsulation

Tags: html, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to encapsulate an SVG line with an arrowhead at the end without any global ids in a React component, (but the question itself has nothing to do with React).

Example fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wzyzqhgh/1/

```
const LinkComponent = ({ x1, y1, x2, y2, color }) => {
  const coordinates = calculateCoordinates(x1, y1, x2, y2)
  const linkStyle = calculateStyles(x1, y1, x2, y2)
  return (<svg style={linkStyle} shapeRendering="geometricPrecision">
    <defs>
      <marker 
        id="arrow" 
        markerWidth={10} 
        markerHeight={10} 
        refX={9} 
        refY={3} 
        orient="auto" 
        markerUnits="strokeWidth"
      >
        <path d="M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z" fill={color} />
      </marker>
    </defs>
    <line
      x1={coordinates.x1}
      y1={coordinates.y1}
      x2={coordinates.x2}
      y2={coordinates.y2}
      strokeWidth={1}
      stroke={color}
      markerEnd="url(#arrow)"
    />
  </svg>)
}
```

This component defines a `marker` locally each time it's rendered, but seems like the `id` of the `marker` is global. So when I do this:

```
ReactDom.render(
  (<div>
    <LinkComponent x1={10} y1={20} x2={100} y2={200} color="red" />
    <LinkComponent x1={10} y1={200} x2={200} y2={10} color="blue" />
  </div>),
  document.getElementById('test')
)
```

The first color is used in both components `marker-end`.

**Question**: How do I encapsulate `marker`s in a single `svg` element so they don't leak out? Is there any other way to reference them in `marker-*` properties than `id`? If it's not possible, how can I achieve similar effects without using `defs`/`marker`s

Comment: You don't. It's id only and ids are global. You could draw all the marker lines individually I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few choices:

1. Pull the marker definition(s) out into a static SVG that is referenced by all LinkComponents, or
2. Generate a random, unique `id` each time.
3. Add the colour to the id, so even if you have duplicate marker definitions, it doesn't matter which one is referenced:

   ```
   id="arrow-{color}"
   ```
4. Don't use markers. Draw the arrowhead yourself.

Comment: Adding the color is a nice touch! Do you have any resources on how would I draw the arrow individually without markers? The only reason I went with the markers in the first place is because I didn't want to calculate the angle of the line and rotate the arrow (triangle) myself.

Comment: See this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737478/block-arrow-using-svg/41743835#41743835