# Referencing SVG marker element *not* through its id attribute

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm writing a svg arrows library for React.

The problem with marker elements that you suppose to define it inside `defs` section. But that section renders only once, and that is a problem with react - I can't know how the next arrow will look like - and when the first arrow is rendered he fixes the arrowHead properties of the next arrows also.

See [here](https://svgwg.org/specs/markers/#MarkerReferences) - it is written that you can access a marker element not through is URL but a child or an `<child-selector>` - what here these? How can I do this?

```
<defs>
  <marker
    id="arrowHead"
    viewBox="0 0 12 12"
    refX="3"
    refY="6"
    markerUnits="strokeWidth"
    markerWidth={headSize}
    markerHeight={headSize}
    orient={`${st.headOrient}`}
  >
    <path d="M 0 0 L 12 6 L 0 12 L 3 6 z" fill={headColor} />
  </marker>
</defs>
<path
  d={`M ${st.x1} ${st.y1} C  ${st.cpx1} ${st.cpy1}, ${st.cpx2} ${st.cpy2}, ${st.x2} ${st.y2}`}
  stroke={lineColor}
  strokeDasharray={`${dashStroke} ${dashNone}`}
  strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
  fill="transparent"
  markerEnd="url(#arrowHead)" // here!! how can i replace it to reference the marker above???
/>
```

Alternatively - does anyone know a way to create a nice customizable arrowhead without using markers?

Comment: Do you mean that you render several arrows inside the same SVG?

Comment: no - each arrow inside is own svg canvas.

Comment: I have created a component that can draw one arrow in 4 possible directions: left, right, up or down. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: no, I want a way to make sure a new marker with new properties is referenced each time the arrow renders.
if this is not possible - maybe you know a way to draw arrowhead without the use of markers?

Comment: Hace you seen the date on the [specification you're referencing](https://svgwg.org/specs/markers/). *W3C Editor’s Draft 16 February 2020* - no browser has had time to implement any of that yet.

Comment: did did not know this.
ok so i can render a marker element without predefining it in defs section?

Comment: what do you mean? data URI and inline it? can you provide some simple example?

Comment: ok so how can i draw a nice customizable arrowhead without using markers?

Comment: Try this perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737478/block-arrow-using-svg

Comment: BTW, you should be able to use your original method. You just have to generate a different marker `id` each time.

Comment: yes, that what i did eventually - but it sucks - i wanted to render the marker as child of the Path element and not reference them.  as Robert said - this feature of SVG2 is not supported yet and you have to reference a marker element in the defs section